# How I can remove a row for a tableview that gets its data from a nested dictionary?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a calss like this :

```
class Datagetterclass {
var datatest = [ "Detergent" :
    [ "tazh" , "Golrang" , "something" ] ,
    "Drinks" :
        [ "hype" , "RedBull" , "Sprite" , "Coca" ],
    "SmallStuff" :
        [ "Gum" , "Pastil" , "Chips" , "Olive" , "Sausage" ]
    ]
```

I made a tableview  using this class's elements and it's working ok 
But when I want to active swipe deleting function because there is no indexpath for this dictionary I can't use the method "remove at index". How can I do it ???

Actually I've tried to use   "remove at index(indexpath.row)" and faced with this error :
         Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'DictionaryIndex' (aka 'DictionaryIndex>')

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are unordered collections. They don't take an integer index. They are not a good choice to be the data source for a table view.

About the only way you can use a dictionary as the data source for a table view is to build an array of all of it's keys using the `keys` method (or `allKeys` if it's an NSDictionary rather than a Swift Dictionary), at startup, and then use the tableview row to index into the array of keys and fetch the appropriate dictionary entry. This approach still isn't good because from one run to the next the `keys` method may return the dictionary keys in different orders.

You should probably use an array of dictionaries (for a single section table view) or an array of arrays of dictionaries for a sectioned table view.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how can I write the code to solve this problem of mine ?